# indexed query to decimate time series results

Tags: database, data-structures, data-science

The context here is I'm scoping a design that slices time-series data at user-defined intervals - too many permutations to simply `roll up` the data (eg, a 2nd `hourly` table, rolled up as (or after) the data ingest).  I am not a database expert, so am hoping to learn if there are standard approaches to this that rely on table indexes, not duplicating the data in new table/collection, or otherwise encoding it a priori by file structure, etc.  Especially if there is a particular db suited to or supporting this load.  A prototype of the backend is in Mongo, but we can easily pivot to a more suited store at this time.

QUESTION: In any mainstream database or similar, is it possible to query a ~time series over a given time window, (efficiently) returning only data points at a consistent interval? (what db and example query, specifically).

My data is a few 10's of gb today, but growing if we're successful.  I'd expect indexes against timestamp to continue to fit ~ok in memory.  A custom file-based schema such as using parquet might work, but an off the shelf DB would be ideal.  By `consistent interval`, i mean some "skip" meaningful to a human, such as

- "every `n`th value", if the data could be assumed to be at a reliable cadence
- or perhaps "first sample per hour", if not and the timestamps were epoch times

Eg, if my data is

| ts | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1 |
| 1002 | 2 |
| 1003 | 3 |
| ... continuous ... |  |
| 1010 | 10 |
| 1011 | 11 |
| ... etc ... |  |
| ... large data set |  |

and query had the parameters:

```
- skip_value:10
- ts:
  - after:1000
  - before:2000
```

the returned set would be:

```
[ (1001, 1), (1011,11), (1021,21) ....  (1991,991) ]
```